# Regex ignoring middle string

Tags: r, regex

I have the dataframe dat1. Is there any way to use str_extract() and regex to extract only "red white 40 R" from colnames(dat1)? I plan on plotting them using facet_wrap later on, but am having trouble extracting the text I want. For my actual code, the R# will always be in the string, however, everything left to the R# can be varied. The expected output after the str_extract() should be txt.

```
dat1 <- data.frame(c(1,2,3,4), c(10, 20, 30, 40),
                   c(100, 200, 300, 400), c(1000, 2000, 3000, 4000))
colnames(dat1) <- c("red G white 40 R3", "red G white 40 R5", 
                    "red H white 40 R7", "red H white 40 R10")
txt <- c("red white 40 R", "red white 40 R", "red white 40 R", "red white 40 R")
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output?

Comment: The text "red white 40 R" is what I am trying to extract.

Comment: To be more precise c("red white 40 R", "red white 40 R", "red white 40 R", "red white 40 R") should be the output after the str_extract(colnames(dat1), ...)

Answer (score 0):

This will really depend on your edge cases. For instance you could use `sub("(red ).* (white 40 R).*", "\\1\\2", colnames(dat1))` but you might as well just write `colnames(dat1) <- rep("red white 40 R", ncol(dat1))` at that point.

Do the words you want to keep change? the numbers? Maybe you want something more robust:

```
sub("(\\w+).*?(\\w+ \\d+ \\d).*", "\\1\\2", colnames(dat1))
```

It's hard to help if we don't know the full use-case for your desired code.

Comment: I hope the edit I made to the post helps, but only the R# in the string will always be present, but everything to the left can be varied.